# Charity want repayment

Tags: volunteering

My local charity want volunteers to wear a new uniform for events even though the old is still valid. For the last event I went down a day before to pick the uniform up. I didn't know where it was stocked and no management was around. I asked another member whose Uncle is on the management board so knows a lot.

He told me I had to pay first. As I had forgotten about it, I promised him to pay the following day, but he refused. I ended up without the uniform.

I've been at the charity for **6 and a half years**, playing various active roles leading new initiatives. They all know me very well and I'm sure management would have allowed me to do this. This member is very bossy because of his Uncle and almost asks like management himself. They protect themselves against the new members that have been there a few weeks not paying later.

I'm leaving at the end of the month because as they no longer value their members. However they don't know this yet suspect it as I haven't turned up for a while. Although they are now requesting money for the uniform I requested.

I don't want to say I wasn't allowed by member X because it will turn into a complaint about them and I will be outnumbered by management team, obviously they stick up for each other.

I don't want to pay as I'm leaving. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're leaving the charity, and the reason you're leaving is the lack of appreciation for their members, and since the uniform is still unworn, it has more value to the charity than to you - you're not going to want to wear it as part of your regular wardrobe after you leave, but they can keep it on hand for some other member to wear in the future.

**There's no reason for you to take, or pay for, the new uniform.**

Go ahead and tell them you're leaving, and the reason why (you can do so without naming names, just describe the general change in culture), and explain that since you were not able to collect the new uniform in time to wear it to the event, and thus it hasn't been used, they can keep it in inventory.

Comment: Dan, I opted to get the uniform as I had a big present in the event. It wasn't required. Although they feel I should pay for it as I requested it and they laid out their own money.

Comment: Did you actually wear the uniform at the event? It sounded from your original post like you did not. If not, then they can keep it and give it to someone else still.

Comment: I didn't. Someone else can have it but no one wants it.

Comment: I've expanded my answer based on these comments. If no other current member wants it, they can just keep it on hand for a future member that's your size.

Comment: Donate it back to them. Write off the purchase cost. Simpler than arguing with them.

Comment: Return it to them. Make sure that you get a receipt that you returned the uniform in an unopened package. If they ask you for payment, you state firmly that you are not going to pay for a uniform, especially since on the one occasion where you would have needed it, some jobsworth's nephew took it upon himself to refuse it. If they insist on payment, tell them that they can sue you. Not paying is much cheaper and much more fun.